# How to find $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z_+} \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{2^n}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I'm trying to calculte the measure of a fat [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), but run into this question:

> How to find $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z_+}  \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{2^n}}$$

Comment: Your series is a super-fast-converging one but I would not bet it admits a nice closed form.

Comment: But you can have fun by proving it is a trascendental number.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's cool, though, unfortunately, my knowledge of transcendental numbers is zero.

Comment: $\approx .3907470740377903$